# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("toString" | "valueOf")[]'

Tags: typescript

I have two properties on an object being passed into a function. I want to constrain the `deps` property on one object's properties to be a *key* of the other object.

E.g.:

```
const config = {
  modules: {
    bar: {
      baz: true,
      deps: ['foo', 'notADep'],
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => {}),
    },
  },
  services: {
    foo: { factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => {}) },
  },
};
```

In the above config, `foo` is valid, but `notADep` is not valid.

Here's my code:

```
function createApp<T extends Config>(config: T) {}

export type Service<T> = {
  factory: () => Promise<() => void>;
  deps?: (keyof T & string)[] | undefined;
}

export type Services<T = any> = Partial<Record<keyof T, Service<any>>>;

export type Modules<T = any> = Record<string, {
  baz: boolean,
} & Service<keyof T>>

interface Config {
  modules: Modules;
  services: Services;
}
```

I'm getting an error on the `config` parameter that

```
Argument of type '{ modules: { bar: { baz: boolean; deps: string[]; factory: () => Promise<() => void>; }; }; services: { foo: { factory: () => Promise<() => void>; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config'.
  Types of property 'modules' are incompatible.
    Type '{ bar: { baz: boolean; deps: string[]; factory: () => Promise<() => void>; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Modules<any>'.
      Property 'bar' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type '{ baz: boolean; deps: string[]; factory: () => Promise<() => void>; }' is not assignable to type '{ baz: boolean; } & Service<string | number | symbol>'.
          Type '{ baz: boolean; deps: string[]; factory: () => Promise<() => void>; }' is not assignable to type 'Service<string | number | symbol>'.
            Types of property 'deps' are incompatible.
              Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("toString" | "valueOf")[]'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"toString" | "valueOf"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBvAsAKBhgFsQATAVwBsBTCALm30MICMBDAJwdwOdbYBeDKB3LUANEz4xS1AA70YAbQDkCECBXiYKsCCgBBACLyVAXUm8+CNsCggOATwYAKAJQYAfDAAKHEERIENQAdBy0IJQAbtQu7l7YAL5ulnyJqTDpUsEcUUjAtNxShOog3DA2dg7OMPHo3n4BQaHhEJExcR71SR5ZvH2JANz4+PDQMGxychhw4WxQ1AZTLvDIKG7DePgI5GB2SOCz1POLUwA8ACow1AAeC2CkEDAAwuBrnitvqAwXHliJIzwtzkDlgUEccmoMAAytRcvlqJdvJgeCVbPYnK4ug1-IFgmc6t4oiAkKRPJtCLIFAB+VwAa2ojhACBgVwAZDBoBwkGB1kozDAAD4wXayZBgaikTYArZAm4gjhgiFQ2HwgoQS4zNhgRzI3ycKBINiUM4AJWooA4pDODKZLIu2lVeQKZ21us85MBwNBMHBkJgAFkyFRaJrMG69ebLdauTyUNpUTB2EIkxoaNrLIkYBynQibYzmayPYCeQsOJUoa9EKhGLwSBQaIogw3aBTOXDnYUYR2ERBpUA)

Comment: I have found [this](https://tsplay.dev/w23bjN) solution that requires you to use `as const` on the config object. If this is sufficient then I can write an answer, if not, what am I missing?

Comment: in `Modules` you are using `Service<keyof T>`. Didn't you mean `Service<T>` ?

Comment: In `Modules`, the values' type is constrained to `{ baz: boolean, } & Service<keyof T>` Why is it `Service<keyof T>`? It seems odd, considering that `deps` is constrained to `keyof T`, and `T` would be `keyof` the `T` from `Modules`. So, within a `Module`, a `Service`'s `deps` would be `keyof keyof T`. I think that's why it's giving you the type `"toString" | "valueOf"`; those are the base instance methods of Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), Vue does this to infer props types.

It relies on inferred generic types to reuse them and self constrain the given arguments.

`M` and `S` refers to the properties `modules` and `services` of the given parameter

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBDAxjai4C8cA3gLABQccAZtrlIgFxwAUAlIQHxwAKUEAWwCWAZ2AAedlzgA3CEIAmnANwUAvhQpIUcAMrAoMoVgkBZADR7uRMpRp08zKQW59Boic+5zFnClQVgMBEAficAa2BECGo9OAAfOEjo2NM2AG0AXXVNcm1UUwgFAFcAGzNLXWsSfzgAIwwAL2Y6iAhyjAA7dTgAMj0DIxNxCytc-LgAYQhO6iEAcxHK6tsqASKy4BFmVao4dIBpOCFOpKiYuFNM5kKS8qWxuw07MUNjLZ3aqkPj0+SL3TXAZvYajKq1NSqcjPCjUYqdHBCGZwLBQYAYGDAACCYDADyqLCwMzm82Y01mC3xnDYZOJlLB3F2aJgxSgpyJFPmOXIFFR6MxOLALF26zuHxqdioDSgn0lewazQQUGKwHMXz2gWCzHSAHJqG0dZYdZ0IDAsQARII6zKWAD0trgBn4UAAhOqqLQcI5WBwXLx+MIxAA6NEidoyYAsLwkOBqNhquVqBN7OBgUoQMCylNSprMGDK1XuuCa7b7PUGo0ms2WsDWu0Op3QN1yj0OBhOX2uAMeENbcOR6PEWPx9VJiHJuCvIbi3YetpZ7Oe+hMH3SNyB4C9sOlCNRzsxuMTlMl7U20dH+oYGUS7P2L3t1d+9c90P9vfSIeH3IpsdPBNxqEgA)

```ts
export type Factory = {
  factory: () => Promise<() => void>;
}

type Service<M, S> = {
  factory: () => Promise<() => void>
  // deps are any keys of the modules or services
  deps?: (keyof S | keyof M)[]
}

type Module<M, S> = {
  baz: boolean
} & Service<M, S>

type Config<M, S> = {
  modules: {
    // For every property of M, inform it's a module with the services context (S)
    [K in keyof M]: Module<M, S>
  }
  services: {
    [K in keyof S]: Service<M, S>
  };
}

// The function will automatically infer the given types
function createApp<M, S>(config: Config<M, S>): Config<M, S> {
  return config
}

createApp({
  modules: {
    bar: {
      baz: true,
      // (property) deps?: ("bar" | "foo" | "plop")[] | undefined
      deps: ['foo', 'notADep'], // error!
      //            ^ Error is located on the string, not the whole line
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }),
    },
    plop: {
      baz: true,
      deps: ['foo', 'notADep'], // error!
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }),
    },
  },
  services: {
    foo: {
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }),
      // (property) deps?: ("bar" | "foo" | "plop")[] | undefined
      deps: [],
    },
    bar: {
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }),

    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was slowly getting towards this, but you've hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly but you could probably do something like this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.4.3#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQIJ5TEgYgQwMYLypIC8SA3qEkgGb6FyoBcSAFAJSkB8SACnDAC2ASwDOYADwduSAG4xhAEy4BuUAF9QoSLEQp0mAMpg4s4XjCiJAFSSQEYAHaLRSUQjjDHAcwDaAXVIkAJ4ycmCAaSQvJGtfRwBXQQAjE39-FlwCIiR1NXBoeGQ0DCQAETAMZyc8YUsbOwgHZ1d3Tx8AoJCg8MVK0RZrABpcrQLdYoMkAFkYRQSAG3rZ%20aWIsFRXeycXNw8vP0CyAJGAYRhHBybG5t2YZIArMAIe9VCqCmDp6McZucWwOtNvEkqk4OlMvQcgAyJDnS72UYgMZeBxwOgWOEXGjCbwSFYAoFbJo7Vr7DpHYL%20EbGUzmQEbYm3MntQ5dalYhHXbYtJD3J4vMJvCgfQT-JYDP6rZbihmbM4XK7IWEVKp9Ry1eq0swWIlcVQfcR0iyS7X0qxm3WMg0gTTI%2014C7uJCOxw47wseHuiS%20ABEyRwcF9HL9NBgMGDI3CAYAXixkuGljhfsKwqLZZLKCBqNQA3AWFmcznYywPAkwEMPkW%20lBJb4AORhmD1kb1xwwBAAQVV9epVZzGIYzDYnBIPH4QjEYAAdHBLDAFrIwKxpGPPup2JXszn1FvqLvDSYdZYC-2mwXaFDGCxV%20OBCJxLP54vl7f15wD9vP3lQEA)

```
export type Factory = {
  factory: () => Promise<() => void>;
}

export type Services<T extends string[] = []> = { [K in T[number]]: Factory };
export type Dependencies<T extends string[] = []> = { deps: T, }

export type Modules<ModuleKeys extends string[] = [], Context extends object = {}> =
  { [M in ModuleKeys[number]]: Factory & Context }


interface Config<ModuleKeys extends string[] = [], ServiceKeys extends string[] = [], Context extends object = {}> {
  modules: Modules<ModuleKeys, Context & Dependencies<ServiceKeys>>;
  services: Services<ServiceKeys>;
}


const config: Config<["bar"], ["foo"], { baz: boolean }> = {
  modules: {
    bar: {
      baz: true,
      deps: ['foo', 'notADep'], // error!
      factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }),
    },
  },
  services: {
    foo: { factory: () => Promise.resolve(() => { }) },
  },
};
```

Edit:
So the problem with your solution are these lines:

```
export type Service<T> = {
  factory: () => Promise<() => void>;
  deps?: (keyof T & string)[] | undefined;
}
```

With `(keyof T & string)[]` you are telling typescript that every key of T is valid that is a string. Everything in Typescript or Js is an object. For example
`keyof number & string` will resolve to `"toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"`. This will also happen if you use a string, object...

If you only want to get the a union of all used keys. You should use a tuple and indexing it with tuple[number] to receive nothing else but the values you want.

```
//e.g.
type Tuple = ["a","b"]
type Union = Tuple[number] // "a"|"b"
```

So why does this work? Remember everything is an object? An array is an object aswell and but all the keys for the values are numbers.
So with `Tuple[number]`you are telling typescript to get all values with a number key.

Ps: You can also do `Tuple[string]` to get all method on an array
My english is trash, so if you don't understand a thing, just ask and  I'll try to help you

Comment: Good solution ! However it's not scalable, I am not sure the author nor any user wants to manually declare every possible modules as Generics. It seem this post is related to big configurations where it's easy to do a typo